# why sbt use Ivy as default, not Maven?

Tags: maven, sbt, ivy

i think Maven is more popular for us. Ivy is so difficult to use.

When using sbt with Maven, it's hard to process many errors for Ivy and Maven's path different.

Why **sbt** use **Ivy**, not **Maven** directly?

Answer (score 3):

I can only guess, but I think it might be because Ivy has a somewhat more flexible dependency management system. Incidentally, this additional flexibility makes it more powerful and also more complicated. For example, in Maven your dependency scopes are fixed (compile, test, runtime, etc) but in Ivy they are not, you can add more if you like. Also, Ivy has more flexible conflict resolvers when two dependencies bring in the same transitive dependency but at different versions; Ivy can be configured on how to select one.

But this is just a guess.